# Looking to leave XP SP3 IE8 for Ubuntu

Tags: application-development, tablet

I am a newbie, so I don't know what results I if any I will get. I have been checking out Ubuntu 9 or some number like that on a flash drive, and it seems like open source software and Ubuntu is the way to go.

A tablet looks like the place I would like to jump in. You know, new OS, new device, new day... It's a new wave, so what should I try?

- Should I go ahead and buy a low-priced tablet and what specs do I look for?
- Should get a Quad core with the most gigabytes?

Maybe an [iView 7-inch Android Multi-touch Tablet](http://www.ensogo.com.ph/products/iview-7in-tablet-11162012.html) or something from China? I think that going for a lower end brand tablet and not spending a lot is worth trying until the learning curve tells me it's time for something else.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are offtopic in most, if not all, Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Hardware (including tablets) recommendations are off topic here. Please ask one question at a time. Consider installing and learning to use Ubuntu (Xubuntu or Lubuntu) in your XP computer first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: Seems you are more after a discussion, recommendations and opinions rather than a 'correct' answer. I would suggest you try out a forum such as http://ubuntuforums.org/

Comment: Yep, http://UbuntuForums.Org is good for the hardware discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you start small and simple; create a LiveUSB by downloading [Xubuntu's ISO file](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)  - and choose the 32-bit version of the newest release, 13.10. Xubuntu is the version of Ubuntu Linux which looks the most like Windows XP, so we're keeping the learning curve as flat as possible.

Then, once the ISO completes its download, download and use the [free Windows program](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) which makes any USB flashdrive into a LiveUSB you can boot from.

Then, reboot your computer and tell it to boot from the LiveUSB, which will allow you to start using Ubuntu Linux without getting a new machine. That way, you can get started today!